# Using RecyclerView to display items each with a button that should start a different RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments

### Outline of Issue

Error: No adapter attached; skipping layout.

Investigation shows the onBindViewHolder of the new RecyclerView is never called.

I have searched and tried a number of alternative solutions but no luck so far. I have tried using one Recycleview to handle both fragment types but ended up with the same issue.

The first RecyclerView works and displays the fragment items as expected, they each have a button that should open a new RecyclerView that lists items from a different data set (and with a different format).

I am quite new to android so would appreciate any help you can offer.

### The onClick code from the onBindViewHolder

```
holder.checklistButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Context context = view.getContext();
            final Intent intent = new Intent(context, ChecklistActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("EVENTPOSITION",mValues.indexOf(holder.mItem));
            intent.putExtra("EVENTID", holder.mItem.getEventID().toString());
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }`
```

### OnCreate of the new activtity

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_single_fragment);
    FragmentManager fm = this.getSupportFragmentManager();
    Fragment fragment = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentContainer);
    if (fragment==null){
        fragment = new ChecklistFragment();        fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragmentContainer,fragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
        fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragmentContainer,fragment).commit();
    }
```

### OnCreate for the new Fragment

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    recyclerView = new RecyclerView(getContext());
    recyclerView.findViewById(R.id.list2);
    Log.i(Configuration.TAG, "Event List Fragment onCreate");
    checkFeed = TheEvents.getInstance();
    Bundle extras = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras();
    String eventID = extras.getString("EVENTID");
    int eventPosition = extras.getInt("EVENTPOSITION");
    System.out.println("this is the eventid " + eventID + " is position: " + eventPosition);
    List<Checklist> feed = checkFeed.getItemAt(eventPosition).getChecklists();
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
    adapter = new ChecklistRecyclerViewAdapter(feed, mListener);
    for (int i = 0; i < feed.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println("this is the checklists " + feed.get(i).getChecklistName());
    }
    System.out.println("CREATED ADAPTER: " + adapter);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

### The RecyclerView list layout

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/list2"
android:name="read.checklist.ChecklistFragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
app:layoutManager="LinearLayoutManager"
tools:context="read.checklist.ChecklistFragment"
tools:listitem="@layout/fragment_checklists_item" />
```

### List item layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/list2item"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">    
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/checklistName"
    style="@style/seventName"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/checklist_name" />
```

### Single Frame layout

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/fragmentContainer"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
    android:layout_margin="30dp"
    app:fabSize="normal"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_add"
    android:id="@+id/fabAddEvent" />
```

Comment: Can u please put the fragment code in 'onCreateView' not 'onCreate'

Comment: I have moved all of the code from 'onCreate' to 'onCreateView' above the line:  View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_checklists_list, container, false); however it is giving the same result.

Comment: did you do it like [this](http://pastebin.com/XM2zuWr5)? if u still have the same error please update your question with the error from the logcat.

Comment: I have now solved the issue. I have refactored the project to work with a single recycler view. Your suggestion of moving to the onCreateView was the missing pice to the puzzle when i initially tried this approach. Currently working toward a tight deadline but plan to upload the solution when i get some free time.